# How to connect array element with innerHTML? e.g. element[0].innerHTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters, innerhtml

I have a problem with  "if" inside "check" function, it's not working at all.
I don't know what i'm doing wrong. 
When hardcoded like so:

```
if(a.innerHTML == nazwa && b.innerHTML == nazwa && c.innerHTML == nazwa){
call(a1, a2, a3, nazwa)
}

(a1 = "a", a2 = "b", a3 = "c")
```

everything works just fine, but when data is from array nothing happens.
Maybe it's something with array[0].innerHTML?
Please help! :D

```js
$(function(){

  var x = "o",
      flag;

  var a = document.getElementById("a"),
      b = document.getElementById("b"),
      c = document.getElementById("c"),
      d = document.getElementById("d"),
      e = document.getElementById("e"),
      f = document.getElementById("f"),
      g = document.getElementById("g"),
      h = document.getElementById("h"),
      i = document.getElementById("i");

  var testy = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "adg", "beh", "cfi", "aei", "gec"];
  
  var styleWin = {"background-color": "yellow",
                   "color" : "red" };
  


  // abc
  // def
  // ghi
  // abc, def, ghi, adg, beh, cfi, aei, gec
  //check if we have 3 in row, if yes, alert winner
  function check(nazwa){  
    //   When hardcoded like so, works perfect!!
    //   if(a.innerHTML == nazwa && b.innerHTML == nazwa && c.innerHTML == nazwa){
    //    call(a1, a2, a3, nazwa)
    //   }
    
    for(var ij = 0; ij < testy.length; ij++){
      testy[ij].split("");
      console.log("cons 0 =  " + testy[ij][0] + " cons 1 = " + testy[ij][1] + " cons 2 = " + testy[ij][2]);
      if(testy[ij][0].innerHTML == nazwa && testy[ij][1].innerHTML == nazwa && testy[ij][2].innerHTML == nazwa){
        call(testy[ij][0], testy[ij][1], testy[ij][2], nazwa);
        console.log("NAZWA " + nazwa);
      }
    }
  };  
  
    function call(f1, f2, f3, n1){
      console.log("Wygrał! " + n1);
      // console.log(testy[0]);
      flag = "end";
      $("#"+f1+",#"+f2+", #"+f3).css(styleWin);  
        
  }
  
  //check if game has ended or player clicks at used field, else put sign in field
  $("div.item").on("click", function(){
    var place = this.innerText;
    if(place == "x" || place == "o"){
      console.log("Niedozwolony ruch!");
    } else if(flag !== "end"){
      this.innerText = x;
      check(x);
    }
  });
  
  //Change between x and o
  $(".container").on("click", function() {
    if(flag !== "end"){
      (x == "o") ? x = "x" : x = "o";
      return x;  
    }
  });
   
  //reset
  $(".reset").on("click", function(){
    $(".item").removeAttr('style');
    $(".item").empty();
    flag = "";
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.over {
  display: grid;
  border: 5px solid red;
  grid-template-columns: auto 300px auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 300px auto;
  grid-template-areas: ". f1 ." ". x ." ". f2 .";
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-areas: "a b c" "d e f" "g h i";
  grid-area: x;
  grid-gap: 0;
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item-a {
  grid-area: a;
}

.item-b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.item-c {
  grid-area: c;
}

.item-d {
  grid-area: d;
}

.item-d {
  grid-area: d;
}

.item-e {
  grid-area: e;
}

.item-f {
  grid-area: f;
}

.item-g {
  grid-area: g;
}

.item-h {
  grid-area: h;
}

.item-i {
  grid-area: i;
}

.fix {
  grid-area: f1;
  height: 100px;
}

.fix2 {
  grid-area: f2;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.item:hover {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="over">
  <div class="fix"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item-a item" id="a"></div>
    <div class="item-b item" id="b"></div>
    <div class="item-c item" id="c"></div>
    <div class="item-d item" id="d"></div>
    <div class="item-e item" id="e"></div>
    <div class="item-f item" id="f"></div>
    <div class="item-g item" id="g"></div>
    <div class="item-h item" id="h"></div>
    <div class="item-i item" id="i"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fix2"><button class="reset">Reset</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I have my answer. If should look like so:

`if(($("#"+testy[ij][0]).text()) == nazwa && ($("#"+testy[ij][1]).text()) == nazwa && ($("#"+testy[ij][2]).text()) == nazwa){`

Answer (score 0):

The code fails because your `testy` variable is an array of Strings, not an array of objects. When you dereference it with something like `testy[ij][0]`, you are getting the string `"a"`, not the object contained in the variable `a`. To fix this, change your `testy` declaration like so:

`var testy = [[a,b,c], [d,e,f], [g,h,i], [a,d,g], [b,e,h], [c,f,i], [a,e,i], [g,e,c]];`

You can also remove the call to `testy[ij].split("");`. That function returns an array and leaves the string `testy[ij]` unchanged. You aren't using the returned array, and so the call to `split` is having no effect.